# Aggregations with map/reduce mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have data which is organized hierarchically and I'd like to compute aggregations at several levels within a single mongodb map/reduce operation. Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
{ street: "A", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users: 1 }
{ street: "A", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users: 2 }
{ street: "B", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users: 3 }
{ street: "B", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users: 2 }
{ street: "C", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users: 4 }
{ street: "C", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users: 3 }
{ street: "A", district: "2", city: "Z", nb_users: 5 }
{ street: "B", district: "2", city: "Z", nb_users: 6 }
{ street: "B", district: "2", city: "Z", nb_users: 3 }
```

Result:

```
{ street: "A", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users_street: 3, nb_users_district: 15, nb_users_city: 29 }
{ street: "B", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users_street: 5, nb_users_district: 15, nb_users_city: 29 }
{ street: "C", district: "1", city: "Z", nb_users_street: 7, nb_users_district: 15, nb_users_city: 29 }
{ street: "A", district: "2", city: "Z", nb_users_street: 5, nb_users_district: 14, nb_users_city: 29 }
{ street: "B", district: "2", city: "Z", nb_users_street: 9, nb_users_district: 14, nb_users_city: 29 }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to do this.

As you are wanting to aggregate by `street`, `district` *and* `city` you will need to use all of them as part of the key of your emitted objects, so your `map` function would most probably look something like this:

```
function(){
  emit ( 
    { street : this.street, district : this.district, city : this.city }, 
    {nb_users : this.nb_users } 
  );
}
```

As the reduce function combines *only* records with matching keys, you will only be able to combine records where both the street, district and city are the same - which means you won't be able to calculate the total for a district or city from these emitted objects as they span multiple streets.

Doing three separate map/reduces into three separate output collections will make the code simpler and easier to understand, and will also remove the redundancy of having `nb_users_district` and `nb_users_city` repeated for every street level row.

In fact, the three separate map/reduce functions would be so simple that you should be able to use MongoDB's built in `group` function, which I believe offers some performance benefits over standard map/reduce.

Comment: Too bad, the code I am using right now is indeed using three sequential map/reduce operations and a merge operation: aggregate by City/District/Street, then aggregate those results by City/District, then again by City only, and finally merge the aggregated results back with the original data. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 2.2 will be introducing a new aggregation framework which will be much faster and perhaps be able to handle this situation better.  However, I do agree with Russell that using 3 m/r's will be much simple in the long run.  If you wanted to adjust your final document to something else like below, you'll be able to do it in a single m/r, but the code gets pretty hairy.  However, it does have the benefit of being more document-like.

```
result: {
  city: "Z",
  nb_users: 29
  districts: {
    "1": {
      nb_users: 15,
      streets: {
        "A": 3,
        "B": 5,
        "C": 7
      }    
    },
    "2" : {
      nb_users: 14,
      streets: {
        "A": 5,
        "B": 9
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for the info. Found it: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework